# How to change the format of a list in R?

Tags: r, list

I would like to convert the format of my list2 to be like list1, where those letters in "from" go to Names column and whatever that is in "to" go to Value column like in list1. In list1, from and to values are associated. For example, "sce00010" goes with "Glycolysis/Glucogneogeneis".

Is there any way to do so? Tnx!

[image]

[image]

Structure of list2:

```
structure(list(from = c("sce00010", "sce00020", "sce00030", "sce00040", 
"sce00051", "sce00052"), to = c("Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis", 
"Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)", "Pentose phosphate pathway", "Pentose and glucuronate interconversions", 
"Fructose and mannose metabolism", "Galactose metabolism")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
      from                                       to
1 sce00010             Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
2 sce00020                Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)
3 sce00030                Pentose phosphate pathway
4 sce00040 Pentose and glucuronate interconversions
5 sce00051          Fructose and mannose metabolism
6 sce00052                     Galactose metabolism
```

structure of list1:

```
c(sce00010= "Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis", 
sce00020 = "Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)", sce00030= "Pentose phosphate pathway", 
sce00040 = "Pentose and glucuronate interconversions", 
sce00051= "Fructose and mannose metabolism", 
sce00052= "Galactose metabolism")
                                                         sce00010             
                                    "Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis" 
                                                         sce00020 
                                      "Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)" 
                                                         sce00030 
                                      "Pentose phosphate pathway" 
                                                         sce00040 
                       "Pentose and glucuronate interconversions" 
                                                         sce00051
                               "Fructose and mannose metabolism" 
                                                         sce00052
                                         "Galactose metabolism"
```

Comment: Look at `strsplit`. And you'd help yourself with `dput(head(list2))` and copy `structure(...)` above as data...

Comment: Tnx, but was not clear

Comment: You have an object in RStudio, presumably named list2. In the terminal, type `dput(head(list2))` and that will output `structure(...)`,for first six. Pasting that above between ``` (three backtics) above and below, makes your data readily available instead of being a picture of data. Hope that is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
list1 <- list2$to
names(list1) <- list2$from
list1
#>                                   sce00010 
#>             "Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis" 
#>                                   sce00020 
#>                "Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)" 
#>                                   sce00030 
#>                "Pentose phosphate pathway" 
#>                                   sce00040 
#> "Pentose and glucuronate interconversions" 
#>                                   sce00051 
#>          "Fructose and mannose metabolism" 
#>                                   sce00052 
#>                     "Galactose metabolism"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>